# Проблема с шаблонизатором php

Tags: php, шаблонизаторы

Есть простой шаблонизатор на PHP:

```
<?php
  define("PATH","http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/");

  class Templater{
    private $title;
    private $path;
    private $copyright = '';
    private $date;
    private $time;

    public function tmp($title,$path=NULL){
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->path = $path;
        $this->date = date("d.m.Y");
        $this->time = date('H:i:s');

        $tmp = file_get_contents(PATH.'themes/'.$this->path);
        $tmp = str_replace('{TITLE}',$this->title,$tmp);
        $tmp = str_replace('{DATE}',$this->date,$tmp);
        $tmp = str_replace('{TIME}',$this->time,$tmp);
        $tmp = str_replace('{COPYRIGHT}',$this->copyright,$tmp);

        return $tmp;
    }
  }
  $templater = new Templater();
?>
```

Папка с шаблоном: themes/

Файл index.php

```
<?php
  require_once 'includes/theme.class.php';
  $title = "Главная страница сайта";
  print $templater->tmp($title,'main.tpl');

$name = "Dmitriy";

?>
```

Почему в самом main.tpl не выводится значение `$name`?. 
Кто подумает, то что tpl файлы php не обрабатывает - у меня в .htaccess прописано

```
RemoveHandler .html .htm 
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html .phtml
```

.tpl Что позволяет использовать в tpl файлах php.

Comment: а где вывод переменной $name ??? Вы ее инициализировали, но не вывели. Или вывели, но я не вижу где именно

Comment: Почетче, пожалуйста. В нынешнем состоянии вопроса у вас $name определяется уже после вывода темплейта.

Кроме того большой вопрос — константа `PATH`. Вы точно хотите `file_get_contents()` мучить через `http://...` ?

Comment: она выводится в main.tpl 
echo $name;

Comment: @Дмитрий Астафьев, main.tpl у вас запрашивается через сеть, вы хотите, чтобы по сети магически еще и переменные летали? Не говоря уж о том, что $name выставляется после всех манипуляци с файлов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так вы используете main.tpl, как текст. Что вы хотите там получить после print?
Если я верно понял задачу, то при такой структуре вам надо объявлять $name до подключения main.tpl и заменить print на eval :)

Упс
Увидел file_get_contnets  - это вообще не понятно... Обращаясь к main.tpl именно так, вы сначала его выполните через интерпретатор php, а потом только обработаете в своем скрипте то, что main.tpl выведет. Соответственно, если в самом main.tpl не объявлена переменная $name, то откуда взяться ее значению позже?

Comment: какой нафиг eval? обычное echo - решение всех проблем

Comment: Чем здесь echo будет отличаться от print?)

Comment: @Антон Смуров, он быстрее =)

Comment: Я рад, что вы это знаете. А теперь прочитайте еще и вопрос, который обсуждается вместе с приведенным кодом.

Comment: @Антон Смуров, а теперь почитайте мой коментарий, который сразу же под вопросом